# CSS Files loaded and unloaded according to jquery functions

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have two css files. Both files already loaded. When a textbox(jQuery datepicker box) clicks 'first.css' want to be loaded and 'second.css' to be unloaded . After selecting the date ,unload the 'first.css'  file and load the 'second.css' file. It is very difficult use Selectors in current stage because these styles are used in many other places.

Is it possible when  clicking  a text box  load 'first.css' and unload 'second.css' .Then on a  onclick function  to vice-versa using jQuery.

Comment: Use the [css] tag, not [css3] or [css-selectors], since your questions have nothing to do with CSS3 or selectors.

Comment: I have an opinion, just an advice. another method, combine 2 css into one, just use rule like `body1.content` and `body2.content`, then only use jquery control `removeClass` and `addClass` to switch `<body class="body1">` and `<body class="body2">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to load both CSS files at page load and toggle between them on click events, you can do so by disabling/enabling the loaded CSS files.

```
function toggleClass() {
  var switcher = $("link[href*='first.css']").attr("disabled");
  $("link[href*='first.css']").attr({"disabled":!switcher});
  $("link[href*='second.css']").attr({"disabled":switcher});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is relatively easy, though it's better if you have only one stylesheet loaded as the page first loads:

```
<head>
    <!-- other stuff -->
    <link href="http://path/to/dayglo.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <!-- any other stuff -->
</head>

<select id="switch">
    <option value="dayglo">Day-Glo</option>
    <option value="dark">Dark</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#switch').change(
    function(){
        var url = 'http://path/to/' + $(this).val() + 'css';
        $('link[rel="stylesheet"]').attr('href',url);
    });
```

Or you can simply place a class-attribute, or add or remove an `id`, in order that the rules are specified with that attribute:

```
body.dayglo h1 {
    /* whatever */
}

body.dark h1 {
    /* whatever */
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#switch').change(
    function(){
        $('body').removeAttr('class').addClass($(this).val());
    });
```

This approach means you need only the one stylesheet, and relies on the specificity of the selectors to apply the various styles.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to achieve this is to add and remove a class from the `body` tag, i.e. have `first` set as the class on `body` then replace it with `second`. If you change your css files to have these classes as part of the selectors then this will give you the same effect as loading and unloading files.